# Is there a way to replace the currently selected text on X11?

Tags: x11, xclip

I stumbled across `xclip` which gives you access to the text you have selected on your active window.

I've been thinking if there was a way to alter such text. The workflow I have in mind is the following

1. Select editable text
2. Press a hotkey
3. Hotkey runs a script that toggles the selection between all caps and lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign a shortcut to a command like:

```
xclip -o -sel p | tr '[:lower:][:upper:]' '[:upper:][:lower:]' | xclip -i -sel c; xdotool key Shift+Insert
```

This assumes <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> pastes from clipboard (if that's not the case, replace `Shift+Insert` with `ctrl+v`). It pipes the text from the primary selection to `tr`, overwrites the clipboard selection with the modified text and then emulates <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) keys press.
Note that the previous content of the clipboard selection will be lost; if needed, you could use the secondary selection as a temporary backup:

```
xclip -o -sel c | xclip -i -sel s
xclip -o -sel p | tr '[:lower:][:upper:]' '[:upper:][:lower:]' | xclip -i -sel c; xdotool key ctrl+v
xclip -o -sel s | xclip -i -sel c
```

Comment: Note: apparently sometimes you have to do `xdotool sleep 0.5 key Ctrl+v` for some reason.